Why does my webform not submit if I use a View element that has a VBO field as part of the View?
I have created a form using the webform module (as opposed to hand crafting) where I want people to click on a Media item to set it 'authorised'.  It is a Media type (I have called 'Submitted Image') that has a few additonal fields, including a boolean for the authorisation.  At the end of the form they confirm what they have done with an overall authorisation of the action which we can then record (among other pieces of data).
These Media items come from a View and this View as a VBO field that allows a user to mark the image as authorised.  This functionality is handled by a custom module that validates the form and provides an addtional custom action (to mark each image as authorised)
If I add a View element to the form and display this View on the form, I cannot seem to submit the form? There are no errors and it just 'hangs' and eventually comes back to the submit button again. I have tried both the page and a block. Xdebug shows nothing as it never halts on a breakpoint.
If I display the View, not as an element, but by placing it as a Block on the form, all works OK?
It seems to be to do with the VBO field that is on the View - remove that and it submits fine.
I have webform-civicrm installed and the contacts concerned are related through that interface, but I do not think this is relevant as a simple form without integration still gives the same issue.
Update - following answer back from jrockowitz the webform module creator.  What I had not appreciated is that my approach created a 'form within a form' i.e. nesting and as @clive in the comments below had correctly pointed out, but I failed to understand properly when I tried to look at the markup. I have now used a different approach to address this by using a Webform Handler.

Unless webform has some special handling for Views with forms, you’ll probably end up with nested <form> tags, which could theoretically cause what you’re describing. Check the markup for nested form tags, at least to cross it off. If that’s the problem, you’ll need to open (or find an existing related) bug report

Thanks Clive, much appreciated and I'll take a look.  I know there are issues with exposed filters (which I am aware of and not using).

I cannot see anything obviously wrong and so have created an issue: https://www.drupal.org/project/webform/issues/3462124

It was the same answer.

@mona-lisa - Mny thanks, I thought I had updated this....  Yes, this did effectively create a 'form within a form'.  I'll put an update into my question so it is crystal clear you cannot do this at the moment
